# Nest regular elements inside SVG

Tags: css, svg

Can I nest *regular* elements inside a `svg` element? For example; my svg will be a triangular outer container and I want `input`, `label`, etc. elements inside the SVG.

Maybe I should use clip to create the triangle instead?

Comment: Why do you need them inside your SVG element? (dom-wise)

Comment: @Dekel its much simpler to produce rather than having an absolutely positioned svg behind other elements, other developers will use my library

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not standards compliant, and as svg feature support varies quite a bit per browser, I would definitely put in the work yourself if you need a consistent result. Depending on the complexity of the triangular container and the desired browser support, CSS3 may be all you need.

Comment: You can nest a foreignObject element inside an svg element and then nest any html element you want within that.

Answer (score 0):

According the to [SVG standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) you can't add an `input` nor `label` inside an SVG element.

There are 14 functional areas or feature sets, which are:

- Paths
- Basic shapes
- Text
- Painting
- Color
- Gradients and patterns
- Clipping, masking and compositing
- Filter effects
- Interactivity
- Linking
- Scripting
- Animation
- Fonts
- Metadata

And those are not one of them :)